# Change icon sort data grid from material ui

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I need to know how to change this icon sort in material ui data grid to another icon
this my code for use data grid component

[image]

```
import { DataGrid, DataGridProps, GridColDef,GridColumnGroupingModel } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
export type TableColDef = GridColDef
export type TableColumnGroupingModel = GridColumnGroupingModel

export const Table = (p: DataGridProps) => {
  return <DataGrid {...p} />
}
```

i tried to change with css and reseach in document i need to solution for work

Comment: We have no information that would allow us to answer this question. At a minimum, we need to see the related rendered HTML code segment, and then also the code that shows your attempt to change the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `DataGrid`'s [slot](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#slots) prop to add slots for `columnFilteredIcon` slot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this sx value:
`<DataGrid ..... sx={{ "& .MuiDataGrid-sortIcon": { color: "green !important" } }} />`
See the MUI doc on [how to customize](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) for more information